# Hive UDF with Python - Print exception on shell

Tags: python, exception, hive, udf

In the code below, Whenever exception is caught, I would like to exit from the program & print the exception on shell

```
#stream.py
import hashlib
import sys
import os
import importlib


for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
        try:
            inpFile = "temp.py"
            execfile(inpFile)
            line1 = line.strip('\n').split('\t')
            print "\t".join(line1)
        except:
            #exception expected "temp.py:File Not Found", how do I exit the code & print the exception on console ? 
            sys.exit(1)
```

Here is the Transform query to call the UDF:

> Create table newtable as Select TRANSFORM(id,name) USING
>   'python stream.py' as (id,name) from mytable;

ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting a specific exception then you should trap that, not *everything*, which is what you are doing.  But there is nothing in your code to generate a "File Not Found" anyway!

EDIT:  question code changed!  We really do wish to trap "everything".  I am using `Exception`, which traps "almost" everything, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

This uses Python 2 syntax:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    try:    
        inpFile = "temp.py"
        execfile(inpFile)
        line1 = line.strip('\n').split('\t')
        print "\t".join(line1)

    except Exception as err:
        print >> sys.stderr, err   #  print to stderr (python 2 syntax)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Yes, but "print" would print a link in the table. Check edit in the question

Comment: No Luck, the above script is throwing runtime  exception "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script".

Comment: Sounds like you are not allowed to use `sys.exit(1)` in hadoop.  Maybe that exception is raised by you exiting with an error - but I'm guessing.   I don't have any experience of hadoop.  Maybe you should be writing to the console or tty (OS dependant) that your shell program is using.  I assume that's what you mean by "Print except on shell".

Answer (score 1):

if you want to catch a specific type of exception (for examle an IOError) you can use

```
  except IOError as e:
```

and access the error string with `e.strerror`

if you want to catch all exception you can use `sys.exc_info()[0]` to access the last error message

for example

```
try:
   1/0
except:
   print sys.exc_info()[0]
```

would print

```
<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>
```

Comment: Yes, but "print" would print a link in the table. Check edit in the question

Comment: correct - if you want to output the error message on stderr you can use
print("message %s",  sys.exc_info()[0], file=sys.stderr)

Comment: Throws a syntax error, Does file=sys.stderr write error to a file ?

Comment: No it writes it to the error io stream. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams for an explanation on the standard io streams

Comment: `print (..., file=sys.stderr)` is Python 3 syntax (or `print_function` from future).  Clearly the OP is using Python 2.

Comment: @cdarke print("Error ", sys.exit(1), file = sys.stderr); is throwing runtime exception  while print("Error ", sys.exit(0), file = sys.stderr); is working well. Any idea why it is not accepting the above statement ?

Comment: @NikolausGradwohl print("Error ", sys.exit(1), file = sys.stderr); is throwing runtime exception  while print("Error ", sys.exit(0), file = sys.stderr); is working well. Any idea why it is not accepting the above statement ?

Comment: @NikolausGradwohl print("message %s", sys.exc_info()[0], file=sys.stderr); is print to sys.stderr but not the shell where I run my python script.

Comment: Have you checked if it's written to a log file? Afaik hive writes logs to a subfolder of /tmp by default

Comment: Why are you putting the `sys.exit()` call in the `print` statement?  That will exit your program.  Which version of python are you using?

Comment: It's writing to the hive stderr, i want it to write to the shell/console from where am actually running the script. Well, thanks for that ! will try & let u know when I figure out.